# jQuery Find any element that contain data attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to get value from `data-supported` which I don't know where this attribute will be.

It can be on `ul`, or `select` or even `div`

Can I find any element that contain `data-supported` and return its value in jQuery?

I don't think this is right

```
dataSupported = $('*[data-supported]');
```

Comment: `$('*[data-supported]')` will return all elements with the `data-supported` attribute.... if you want the value of the attribute then `$('*[data-supported]').data('supported')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny you might want to answer here I will accept your question. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('*[data-supported]')` will return all elements with the data-supported attribute.... if you want the value of the attribute then

```
var dataSupported = $('*[data-supported]').data('supported')
```